# Python regex hours to minutes

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of strings written in hours that I want converted to minutes

Some example input strings:

```
50 hour
5 hrs
3 hours
5hrs
1hour
```

I'm trying to come up some regex that will capture all of them and convert the whole thing to an integer that the minute value

The above will turn into:

```
3000
300
180
300
60
```

I'm not too familiar with regex. I started playing around with something like this:

```
re.sub(r'^\d+[a-z]', 'blah', string)
```

However that doesn't appear to catch much at all. Only situations where theres a single digit followed by a letter. Furthermore, I'm not sure how to actually do the conversion into minutes

Comment: Is the input always going to be in hours? What else is going to be the same in the input every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) can accpet a replace function instead of a replacement string. The function will be called with match object, and the return value of the function is used as a replacement string.

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> strings =[
...     '50 hour',
...     '5 hrs',
...     '3 hours',
...     '5hrs',
...     '1hour',
... ]
>>> 
>>> for original in strings:
...     replaced = re.sub(r'(\d+)\s*(?:hours?\b|hrs?\b)',
...                       lambda m: str(int(m.group(1)) * 60),
...                       original)
...     print('{} => {}'.format(original, replaced))
... 
50 hour => 3000
5 hrs => 300
3 hours => 180
5hrs => 300
1hour => 60
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Get first all digits string from the data by regular expression.
2. use map to convert from String to  Integer.
3. use join or for look to generate final output.

**Code**:

```
>>> import re
>>> data = """50 hour
... 5 hrs
... 3 hours
... 5hrs
... 1hour"""
>>> v = re.findall("([\d]+) *h", data)
>>> v
['50', '5', '3', '5', '1']
>>> v = map(int, v)
>>> v
[50, 5, 3, 5, 1]
>>> [i*60 for i in v]
[3000, 300, 180, 300, 60]
>>> data1 = ""
>>> for i in v:
...     data1 += "\n%s"%(i*60)
... 
>>> print data1

3000
300
180
300
60
>>> 

>>> print '\n'.join([str(i*60) for i in v])
```

Best to go with string processing.

Comment: Hmm...I'm not sure if this is useful or not, however this will also match `111 home` or `111 has`, etc.

Comment: :) yes, regular expression is risky. we can add `or` condition in re which given by falsetru in his answer. I will go with string processing for such kind of inputs.